# Unable to generate legend using python / matlibplot for 4 lines all labelled

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Want labels for Bollinger Bands (R) ('upper band', 'rolling mean', 'lower band') to show up in legend. But legend just applies the same label to each line with the pandas label for the first (only) column, 'IBM'.

```
# Plot price values, rolling mean and Bollinger Bands (R)
ax = prices['IBM'].plot(title="Bollinger Bands")
rm_sym.plot(label='Rolling mean', ax=ax)
upper_band.plot(label='upper band', c='r', ax=ax)
lower_band.plot(label='lower band', c='r', ax=ax)
#
# Add axis labels and legend
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Adjusted Closing Price")
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I know this code may represent a fundamental lack of understanding of how matlibplot works so explanations are particularly welcome.

Comment: How about trying `plt.legend(loc='upper left')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably that whatever `upper_band` and `lower_band` are, they are not labeled.

One option is to label them by putting them as column to a dataframe. This will allow to plot the dataframe column directly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y  =np.random.rand(4)
yupper = y+0.2
ylower = y-0.2

df = pd.DataFrame({"price" : y, "upper": yupper, "lower": ylower})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df["price"].plot(label='Rolling mean', ax=ax)
df["upper"].plot(label='upper band', c='r', ax=ax)
df["lower"].plot(label='lower band', c='r', ax=ax)

ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Otherwise you can also plot the data directly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y  =np.random.rand(4)
yupper = y+0.2
ylower = y-0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y,      label='Rolling mean')
ax.plot(yupper, label='upper band', c='r')
ax.plot(ylower, label='lower band', c='r')

ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

In both cases, you'll get a legend with labels. If that isn't enough, I recommend reading the [Matplotlib Legend Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) which also tells you how to manually add labels to legends.